# multipart/form-data handling in Typescript Hapijs

Tags: node.js, typescript, httprequest, multipartform-data, hapi.js

I am trying to make an API that can accept and parse a CSV file using HapiJS in typescript. I tested the following API out in nodeJS and it turned out pretty fine.

```
    server.route({
    path: '/file',
    method: 'POST',
    config: {
        handler: (req, h) => {
            let results = []
            let count = 0
            const payload = req.payload
            const data = payload.files
            data.pipe(csv({ headers: false }))
                .on('data', (data) => results.push(data))
                .on('end', () => {
                    results.forEach(result => {
                        console.log(result['0'])
                    })
                });
            return "file read"
        },
        payload: {
            output: 'stream',
            parse: true,
            allow: 'multipart/form-data'
        }
    }
})
```

I tried to replicate this in Typescript and has been at it for quite long. Ive got the following questions:

1. How do I cast a payload object into some usable type? I have my payload object throwing:

```
     Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"files"' can't be used to index type 'string | object | Buffer | Readable'.
      Property 'files' does not exist on type 'string | object | Buffer | Readable'.
    
    37                 const data = payload['files']
```

I have created an interface but has no idea how to force Payload to use this. I also cant find a class the payload interface could extend.

2. This is the biggest issue. The allow property of the payload option isnt working for me somehow.

```
              payload: {
                  output: 'stream',
                  parse: true,
                  //allow: 'multipart/form-data',
              },
```

As soon as I uncomment the allow property and make a POST request, POSTMAN throws a 415 Unsupported Media Type error. Even though POSTMAN request does have a valid multipart/form-data.
How do i retrieve this request?

Comment: What does your interface look like?

Comment: @Christian currently,  I have not implemented anything since Im not sure what to extend to get Payload to have the file property. Any thoughts on the multipart issue?

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be `file` and not `files` on `payload`?

Comment: It was supposed to be so. But apparently, files worked and file threw an error. Maybe im doing somethin wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the payload config is incorrect.
[Version 19.0.0](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/issues/4017) introduced a breaking change with regards to multipart configuration.

From this version and onwards the `multipart` property of the payload configuration is by default `false` meaning you have to specify it to be something else than `false` to make it accept multipart payloads.

According to the [docs](https://hapi.dev/api/?v=20.0.2#-routeoptionspayloadmultipart) it should be set to `true` or using an object containing a specification for the `output` property.

So try this:

```
payload: {
    parse: true,
    allow: 'multipart/form-data',
    multipart: { output: 'stream' },
}
```

As for the compile error, you could use the `any` type for converting:

```
const payload: any = req.payload
const data = payload.files
```

Comment: Glad to hear it! Please mark the answer as accepted (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

For the second point, you can try to enforce the type of your payload.

Example:

```
const { files } = request.paylad as YourInterface;
```